# If $g$ is bounded and satisfies $g(x) = f(x)$, then $g$ is integrable and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$ and $E$ be a finite subset of $[a,b]$.

Show that if $g$ is bounded function which satisfies $g(x) = f(x)$,   $\forall x\in[a,b]\backslash E$, then $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$.

Proof: Suppose $g$ is bounded function which satisfies $g(x) = f(x)$,   $\forall x\in[a,b]\backslash E$,  Then since $g(x)$ is bounded so is the difference of $f(x) - g(x)$. Then  let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) = 0$  for some finite numbers of [a,b] .  Then$\int_{a}^{b} h(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} [f(x) - g(x)]dx =  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx -\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = 0$.

Then  $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$.

Is my proof ok? Any feedback/help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No. $h$ need not be $0$ everywhere. (But $h(x)$ is $0$ except, perhaps, for a finite number of points.)

Comment: Now it is okay. However, the line should not end with $\dots=0$ but should start with $0=\dots$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.